# Bottom empty arrow on div

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

How can I make the middle of the arrow transparent?

```
#myArrow {
    width:200px;   
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
    border-bottom:1px solid #0099B4;
}

#myArrow:after {
    content:"";
    border-color: #0099B4 transparent transparent transparent;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:12px;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-24px;
    left:45%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rj75qcfa/

Comment: What do you mean by `the middle of the arrow`? I just don't get it.

Comment: do u mean that u don;t want to fill this arrow??

Comment: I just want the border to be visible, the middle needs to be empty. George solution worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `:before` to do a similar thing to what you are doing, just with a pixel off the top, a higher `z-index` and a white border:

```
#myArrow:before {
    content:"";
    border-color: #FFF transparent transparent transparent;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:12px;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-23px;
    left:45%;
    z-index:1;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rj75qcfa/1/)

Note: I would actually have your background arrow bottom property at `-25px` and this white arrow at `-24px`, so as not to have your white arrow overlap the top of your line, like so: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rj75qcfa/6/).

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what i want

Comment: Glad to have helped. (:

Answer (score 2):

## [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rj75qcfa/7/)

```
body{background:#ccc;}
#myArrow {
    width:200px;   
    height:1px;
    position:relative;
    margin:100px auto;
}
#myArrow:before {
content: "";
width: 14px;
height: 14px;
position: absolute;
top: -7px;
margin-left: -7px;
left: 50%;
border-top: 2px solid #0099B4;
border-left: 2px solid #0099B4;
transform: rotateZ(-135deg);
}
#myArrow:after {
content: "";
width: 92px;
height: 2px;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
background: #0099B4;
box-shadow: 110px 0 #0099B4;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm loving it! Great job.